# How to preview images inside mybundle symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to preview images which stored inside mybundle/image folder. but i can not get proper image path for view images which name is dynamic. 
 here is the code.

```
 // inController
$image = $this->get('file_locator');
$path = $image->locate('@AcmeMyBundle/uploads/images/my_img.jpg');

 return $this->render('images/myaction.html.twig', array(
        'path'=>$path,
    ));


 //in myaction.html.twig
  {% image '@SeStorageBundle/uploads/images/'{{ image.name }} %}
    <img src="{{ asset_url }}" width="100%" height="100%" alt="my alt of image" class="pull-left">
    {% endimage %}
```

Comment: Is your 'myBundle' in 'Acme' folder? if not remove "@Acme". You are rendering "show.html.twig" but you are trying to preview the image in "myaction.html.twig". What is happening there?

Comment: yes my bundle is in Acme folder and myaction denote show.html.twig.

Answer (score 0):

If the link to your image is correct, then try using `asset` to render the image like this:

```
<img src ="{{asset(path)}}"/>
```